# webrtc event.candidate has many values

Tags: websocket, webrtc

By following this [**tutorial**](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/webrtc-for-beginners.html)(for beginners)

i created the offerer and answerer ,, i used `onicecandidate()`

```
function onicecandidate(event) {
       if (!peerConnection || !event || !event.candidate) return;
       var candidate = event.candidate;
       // POST-ICE-to-other-Peer(candidate.candidate, candidate.sdpMLineIndex);
}
```

---

`onicecandidate()` event called many times before the awnserer even created 
but as tutorial says that i need to post ice to other peer (used Websocket)
and `(candidate.candidate, candidate.sdpMLineIndex)` got many values ..

so do i need to send all values of `event.candidate` or i need to send the last value only ?

and can i connect only using SDP (Session Description Protocol ) only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send all candidates, it's normal behaviour.

Also this method can be called during active connection and you also should send new value to opponent. ICE engine works all the time and searches the shortest path for communication between you and opponent.

> and can i connect only using SDP (Session Description Protocol ) only
>   ?

not sure what you mean exactly, but answer is No. You need a communication protocol for signalling. It could be Websockets, XMPP or others.

Comment: any idea why on firefox onicecandidate(event) the event value null?

Comment: which version of Firefox you use? time to time I also notice some issues on Firefox. Try to upgrade to latest

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the `event.candidate` values when the other peer connects.
Then you can start sending values..
But before connecting you don't send them.